# Low R-squared for logistic regression while every variable is significant

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, r-squared

I'm performing a multiple logistic regression on my data. Could someone explain how a multiple logistic regression with only significant variables has a low R-squared compared with a multiple logistic regression with all variables (significant plus non significant)?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "with only significant" this implies you have removed insignificant variables, which leads to invalid inference and worse predictions.  But to your point, it depends on "low" and which $R^2$ measure you are using.  If using the Nagelkerke and related pseudo $R^2$, these tend to run lower than the $R^2$ that you traditionally compute in a linear model with continuous $Y$.  Give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can contribute to the model fit even if their share is not significant. In the case of an ordinary linear regression you can expect the $R^2$ to rise with the number of predictors. That is why the $adjusted R^2$ was invented. Even random variables can randomly help to improve the model fit in the sample (which is of course overfitting and will not be reproducible with a test dataset). And then there is still a chance, that some of your extra variables are actually bringing in worthwile information but the power of the significance test was not big enough.